# Error getting BeanDescriptor for path

Tags: java, playframework, ebean

I tried to fetch some data from a db using Ebean ORM. I have 3 tables named `deal` and `deal_company_branch` and `company_branch`. `deal_company_branch`is the associate entity. I wrote a query to fetch data,

```
select d.* from deal d, deal_company_branch dcb where d.deal_id=dcb.dealId and dcb.branchId=3
```

And then I tried to do the same thing using Ebean ORM like following,

```
DealDAO.find.fetch("deal").fetch("deal_company_branch").where()
            .and(Expr.eq("deal.deal_id", "deal_company_branch.dealId")
                    , Expr.eq("deal_company_branch.branchId", branchId)).findList();
```

When I'm executing this I'm getting,

> ERROR:Error while retrieving categories:Error getting BeanDescriptor for path deal from com.de.models.Deal

How may I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

So:

- `fetch("deal_company_branch")` ... that looks like a table name when it should instead be a property name and it is optional so you are probably best to leave it out unless you truely want to fetch that data.
- .and`(Expr.eq("deal.deal_id", "deal_company_branch.dealId")` ... you should leave this out entirely
- `Expr.eq("deal_company_branch.branchId", branchId)).findList();` ... again that looks like a table.column reference rather than the logical property path.

This almost looks like a `ManyToMany` relationship but you don't include you model. In most cases for ORM queries you should include your model objects so that people can understand better what you are trying to do.

It looks like you should just do:

```
DealDAO.find.where().eq("companies.branch.id", branchId).findList();
```

This assumes the Deal entity has a @ManyToMany to "companies" which has a @ManyToOne to "branch" which has an @Id id property.

Ebean will understand from the property paths ("companies.branch.id") what joins it needs to make to support the where clause (and order by clause and fetching).